# Laravel dd() function logouts user

Tags: php, laravel

I created a custom login and custom middleware and
When I try to die dump anywhere it logouts the user what seems to be the problem?

Login Controller:
public function login(Request $request){

```
// flash::success('Succesfully login')->important();

$client = new Client();
  try {
    $res = $client->request('POST', 'http://api.fstbx.com/api/user/login', [
      'headers' => [
             'Accept' => 'application/json',
             'Client-Key' => 'p947KVCgE7PyXLdZpfqOSIg4OwIla2BWdSPzdoqf'
         ],
      'form_params' => [
        'username' => $request->get('username'),
        'password' => $request->get('password')
      ]
    ]);
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    Flash::error('Invalid login credentials.');
    return redirect('/login');
  }



  $info = json_decode((string) $res->getBody(), true);      
  $request->session()->put('authUser',$info['user']);
  $request->session()->put('authToken',$info['access_token']);
  $request->session()->put('authRole',['1','2']);

  $role = [];
  $role = ['1','2'];

  $user =  User::createAuth($info['user'],$info['access_token'],$role);

  return redirect('/');
```

}

Custom Middleware

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!empty(session('authUser'))){

```
        // $user = $request->session()->get('authUser');
        $user = session('authUser');

        // $token = $request->session()->get('authToken');
        $token = session('authToken');
        // $role = $request->session()->get('authRole');
        $role = session('authRole');

        User::createAuth($user,$token,$role);
        return $next($request);

    }
    return redirect('/login');

}
```

User Model

public static function createAuth($userData, $userToken,$userRole)
    {
        $user = new User();

```
    $user->name = $userData['name'];
    $user->email = $userData['email'];
    $user->avatar = array_rand(User::get_avatar());
    $user->token = $userToken;
    $user->roles = $userRole;

    Auth::login($user);

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: This is not imgur, [please don't post screenshots of code or error msgs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Edit your question and add the actual code.

Comment: I don't see any `dd()` in the code you've shown - where are you doing that?

Comment: edited sorry, didn't include any dd(), but if I use dd() in any controller it logouts the authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

adding this code on my custom middleware solved my problem
$request->session()->regenerate();